# Как подключить более раннюю версию библиотеки, если Студия твердит, что доступна только последняя?

Tags: android-library

Мне нужно подключить библиотеку: com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.2.1, а Студия пишет, что доступна только com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.1.2. Но я нашел нужную версию здесь: 
[bintray / jcenter / com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker / 1.2.1](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.wdullaer%3Amaterialdatetimepicker/1.2.1) и здесь: https://maven-repository.com/artifact/com.wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/1.2.1 но подключить я не смог - Студия просто не скачивает нужную версию. Пожалуйста, подскажите как это сделать.

Comment: С новой приложение не компилируется надо переписывать код

Answer (score 1):

ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ!!! Всего лишь изменил эту строку: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' на classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
Как это понимать? Это баг в build:gradle:3.3.2?